# Mouse hover replaces wrong img src

Tags: jquery

So, I have a strange bug. if very [fast move mouse around the page](http://youstart.ru/sample/olo/) jquery replaces the wrong img src in the square blocks with preview.

this is **js code**:

```
  $('.mini-info').bind('mouseenter', function() {   
    var xex = $(this).position().left;
    var yey = $(this).position().top; 
    sim = $('img', this).attr('src');
    kuda = $('a', this).attr('href');


    $('#bcase div.'+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('active').css({
      'top' : yey,
      'left' : xex
    }).attr({'onclick': 'location.href="'+kuda+'"'});

    var omg = $('#bcase div.'+$(this).attr('id')+' div.b').length;

    $('#bcase div.'+$(this).attr('id')+' div.b').css({
      'width': wid/omg
     });
  });   



  $('#bcase > div').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    $('.mini-info#'+$(this).attr('class')+' img').attr({'src': sim});
  });
```

It's possible to fix?

*Normal work is when you move mouse upon one of the square block with preview, script will change image under the mouse. It's work fine. But the bug above is not good...*

Comment: Please paste the relevant code into your question rather than making us go try to find it in a web page we are not familiar with.

Comment: I thought that the best in living example. Ok, just a minute.

Comment: a working link is worth including too, but you will get a lot more answers if you paste in JUST the relevant code for people to look at without having to reverse engineer how your page works and where the code is.  In this case now, you've included a lot of extra stuff.  Including JUST the relevant parts of the HTML and JS is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mouseleave event, you use `sim`variable which is define in mouseenter event.
Then with fast mouse mouvement, the mouseenter of an other div will be called before the mouseleave of previous event.

You have to change your arch. For example, when you create the new div in mouseenter, bind the mouseleave event at this point.
Something lke that (not tested):

```
$('.mini-info').bind('mouseenter', function() {   
  var xex = $(this).position().left;
  var yey = $(this).position().top; 
  var sim = $('img', this).attr('src');
  kuda = $('a', this).attr('href');


  $('#bcase div.'+$(this).attr('id')).addClass('active').css({
    'top' : yey,
    'left' : xex
  }).attr({'onclick': 'location.href="'+kuda+'"'})
  .bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
    $('.mini-info#'+$(this).attr('class')+' img').attr({'src': sim});
  });

  var omg = $('#bcase div.'+$(this).attr('id')+' div.b').length;

  $('#bcase div.'+$(this).attr('id')+' div.b').css({
    'width': wid/omg
   });
});
```

see the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/ptJQy/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tested this code and this fix doesn't solve problem.

Comment: Maybe by adding 'var sim' to declare sim in this function.

Comment: No, `var x` will declare the variable in the function (and accessible to function into this function (closure)), on each call. `x` will not create a variable on each call and will use always the same variable.

Comment: See this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/8WAVj/1/ to compare with and without var